# filter data.table using vector

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having a hard time solving this issue: for a given data.table, can I filter all rows that pass a criteria an all columns?

example:

```
dt <-data.table(col_a = c(1,1,0,0,1),
                col_b = c(50,0,0,1,0),
                col_c = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                col_d = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                col_e = c(1,0,0,0,10))
```

I want to return the rows that pass the filter<-c(T,F,F,F,T) - so row number 5

I've tried `dt[, filter]` - tells me that 'filter' is not found

tried `dt[,c(T,F,F,F,T)]` this returns a string `[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

Can I solve this by only using data.table?

Comment: In your vector `filter`, there are. two `T`s.  So, it should filter two rows instead of row number 5

Comment: There's no such row which passes that filter. If you're expecting 5th row, then I guess you need `col_b = c(50,0,0,1,0)`.

Comment: @samadhi do this `as.logical(10)`, then you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear from the description of the post.  Based on the comments, the OP wants to select the rows that matches the values in `filter`.  In order to do that, first convert the columns to `logical`, replicate the `filter` to make the dimensions same before doing the comparison `==`, get the `rowSums`, check if it equal to `ncol` of original dataset for subsetting the rows

```
dt[rowSums(dt[, lapply(.SD, as.logical)] == filter[col(dt)])== ncol(dt)]
#   col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e
#1:     1     0     0     0    10
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` to single string and then compare

```
dt[dt[, do.call(paste0, lapply(.SD, function(x) +(as.logical(x))))] 
         == paste(+(filter), collapse = "")]
```

---

Or another approach is to loop through the columns, store the boolean comparison output as a `list` of `vector`s and `Reduce`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', ncol(dt))
for(j in seq_along(dt)) lst1[[j]] <- as.logical(dt[[j]]) == filter[j]
dt[Reduce(`&`, lst1)]
```

Or a similar approach with `Map/Reduce`

```
dt[dt[, Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, lapply(.SD, as.logical), filter))]]
```

Comment: changed the input dt - still does not work as I would like it to work. I don't understand why I get 2 rows as results and not one (the last one)

Comment: @iuliux What is your expected output

Comment: @iuliux If you pass two TRUEs, what do you expect `c(T,F,F,F,T)`

Comment: I was expecting dt[filter]
`#    col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e
#1:     1     0     0     0    10` as only that row matches the filter

Comment: checking now - I've realized that I was applying the filter on the rows and not on the columns. the solution provided seams to work on the test dt but it's really slow on the actual data.table (24million rows x 392 columns)

Comment: @iuliux I added some more approaches.  May be, it would help

Comment: thanks for all the options. The Map/Reduce is quite fast too. In the end I think I need to think of a way to do the filtering (as it was suggested) on the long representation of the data (I'm doing a dcast before just to read it better). I'll present my solution once I get to an acceptable form.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the size of your actual dataset, you might be better off to convert it into a long format and then perform the filtering:

```
ans <- melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.vars="rn")[,
    value := as.logical(value)][,
        if (all(value==filter)) rn, rn]$V1
```

one timing:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nc <- 392
nr <- 2e6
filter <- sample(c(1,0), nc, TRUE)
loc <- which(filter>0L)
M <- matrix(sample(c(1,0), nc*nr, TRUE), nrow=nr)
DT <- as.data.table(M)

system.time({
    ans <- melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.vars="rn")[,
        value := as.logical(value)][,
            if (all(value==filter)) rn, rn]$V1
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.20    0.84    1.72
```

---

some other options but not as fast as converting into a long format:

```
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(0L)
nc <- 392
nr <- 1e5
filter <- sample(c(1,0), nc, TRUE)
loc <- which(filter>0L)
M <- matrix(sample(c(1,0), nc*nr, TRUE), nrow=nr)
DT <- as.data.table(M)

# filter <- c(T,F,F,F,T)
# DT <- data.table(c(1,1,0,0,1), c(50,0,0,1,0), c(0,0,0,0,0), c(0,0,0,0,0), c(1,0,0,0,10))
# M <- as.matrix(DT)

loc <- which(filter>0L)
sumF <- sum(filter)

DTo_f <- copy(DT)
DTj_f <- copy(DT)

#Spare matrix
sm_f <- function() {
    sM <- as(M, "dgTMatrix")
    ixDT <- data.table(R=sM@i+1L, C=sM@j+1L, I=1L)
    univ <- data.table(R=rep(1:nr, each=length(loc)), C=rep(loc, nr), U=1L)
    mgDT <- merge(univ, ixDT, by=c("R", "C"), all=TRUE)
    mgDT[, if(!(anyNA(U) | anyNA(I))) R, R]$V1
}

#melt
m_f <- function() {
    melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.vars="rn")[,
        value := as.logical(value)][,
            if (all(value==filter)) rn, rn]$V1
}

#order
o_f <- function() {
    non0 <- DTo_f[, {
        m <- as.matrix(.SD)
        ri <- replace(col(.SD), .SD==0L, NA_integer_)
        as.data.table(matrix(ri[order(row(.SD), ri, na.last=TRUE)], nrow=.N, byrow=TRUE))
    }]
    non0[setNames(as.list(c(loc, rep(NA_integer_, nc - length(loc)))), names(DTo_f)),
        on=.NATURAL, which=TRUE]
}

#join
j_f <- function() {
    setindexv(DTj_f, names(DTj_f))
    DTj_f[, names(DTj_f) := lapply(DTj_f, as.logical)]
    DTj_f[as.list(as.logical(filter)), on=names(DTj_f), which=TRUE]
}

microbenchmark(sm_f(), m_f(), o_f(), j_f(), times=1L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 sm_f() 9.134432 9.134432 9.134432 9.134432 9.134432 9.134432     1
  m_f() 2.020081 2.020081 2.020081 2.020081 2.020081 2.020081     1
  o_f() 3.413685 3.413685 3.413685 3.413685 3.413685 3.413685     1
  j_f() 7.149763 7.149763 7.149763 7.149763 7.149763 7.149763     1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this should answer the question.

Reproduce your data:

```
library(data.table)

dt <-data.table(col_a = c(1,1,0,0,1),
                col_b = c(50,0,0,1,0),
                col_c = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                col_d = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                col_e = c(1,0,0,0,10))
filter<-c(T,F,F,F,T)
```

Now create a variable that is checking for non-zero values in each row and subset accordingly

```
to_subset = apply(dt, 1, function(x) {
  all((x > 0) == filter)
  })

# the output you are looking for
dt[to_subset]

#    col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e
# 1:     1     0     0     0    10
```

The code can be collapsed to be more concise.

```
dt[apply(dt, 1, function(x) all((x > 0) == filter))]

#    col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e
# 1:     1     0     0     0    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which(colSums((df>0)==filter)==nrow(df))` to get index

```
> which(colSums((df>0)==filter)==nrow(df))
col_e 
    5
```

such that

```
> df[which(colSums((df>0)==filter)==nrow(df))]
   col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e
1:     1     0     0     0    10
```